# Estimating $\pi(x)$ in terms of logarithmic integral

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I have come across the following exercise from Hildebrand's notes on analytic number theory (unfortunately, the link on the author's webpage has expired).

> Let $0<\alpha<1$ be fixed. Show that if
> $$
> \theta(x)=x+O\left(x \exp \left(-c(\log x)^\alpha\right)\right) \quad(x \geq 2)
> $$
> with some positive constant $c$, then
> $$
> \pi(x)=\operatorname{Li}(x)+O\left(x \exp \left(-c^{\prime}(\log x)^\alpha\right)\right) \quad(x \geq 2)
> $$
> with some (other) positive constant $c^{\prime}$ (but the same value of the exponent $\alpha$).

I tried to apply partial summation:
$$
\pi(x)=\sum_{p \leq x} 1
=\sum_{p \leq x}\log p\cdot\frac{1}{\log p}
=\frac{\theta(x)}{\log x}+\int_2^x\frac{\theta(t)}{t(\log t)^2}dt.
$$
However the second (error) term is too big:
$$
\int_2^x\frac{1}{(\log t)^2}dt\ll\frac{x}{(\log x)^2},
$$
and I'm not sure if one can bound it by $O\left(x \exp \left(-c^{\prime}(\log x)^\alpha\right)\right)$. Also, I don't see how the logarithmic integral may appear in the partial summation.

Any help or hint on this problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've started off well—but then you used something much weaker than the prime number theorem in the integral. Instead write $\theta(t) = t + (\theta(t)-t)$, split into two integrals, and use the hypothesis of the statement (which is always good to try to arrange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$
\pi(x)-\operatorname{Li}(x)=\int_{2^-}^x{\mathrm d[\theta(u)-u]\over\log u}={\theta(x)-x\over\log x}+\int_2^x{\theta(u)-u\over u(\log u)^2}\mathrm du,
$$

it suffices to show that the remaining integral on the right hand side is $O(xe^{-c'(\log x)^\alpha})$. Plugging in the bound $\theta(x)-x=O(xe^{-c(\log x)^\alpha})$ gives

\begin{aligned}
\int_2^x{\theta(u)-u\over u(\log u)^2}\mathrm du
&\ll\int_2^x{e^{-c(\log u)^\alpha}\over(\log u)^2}\mathrm du\ll\int_2^xe^{-c(\log u)^\alpha}\mathrm du \\
&\le(\sqrt x-2)e^{-c(\log2)^\alpha}+\int_{\sqrt x}^xe^{-c(\log u)^\alpha}\mathrm du \\
&\le(\sqrt x-2)e^{-c(\log2)^\alpha}+(x-\sqrt x)e^{-c(\log\sqrt x)^\alpha} \\
&\ll xe^{-c'(\log x)^\alpha}
\end{aligned}

with $c'=2^{-\alpha}c$.